# 1 pixel difference between Mac Safari and Mac Firefox

Tags: windows, macos, text, rendering, pixel

Here is my page that I am working on:

http://www.lethalmonk6.byethost24.com/index.html

On Macs, if you look closely, there is a 1 pixel shift in the Y positioning of the sidebar and the links for the projects to the right of them. This occurs in Safari for Mac, but not Firefox for Mac.

On Windows, everything is aligned in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and even in IE(!).

My gut feeling is that this is occurring due to the text rendering differences between each OS, but Firefox doesn't seem to exhibit this in either OS.

It is barely noticeable, but it is really bugging me. Is there anything I can do to remedy this?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1956895/Picture%201.png - Mac Firefox

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1956895/Picture%202.png - Mac Safari

Comment: No, sorry, I don't see what you mean. Other than the fonts being different, I can't see any problems. Well, the page has a horizontal scrollbar on my 23" monitor, but that's by design, isn't it?

Comment: Heres what I'm talking about if you inspect the element in Safari:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1956895/Screen%20shot%202011-12-15%20at%2010.40.17%20AM.png

Notice the slight gap between the top of the left sidebar and the projects to the right.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see it. Now while I'm not sure what the exact cause is, you do have a lot of errors in the HTML - <div>s inside <a>s, <center>s inside <ul>s, etc. Maybe those cause some problems in some browsers. (I don't have a Mac here, so I can't test if correcting the errors solve the problems in Mac Safari). By the way, the site looks terrible in Opera.